# Assign an array to a collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

From the code it's very easy to see what I want, but nothing works so far:

```
Sub test()
    Dim C As New Collection
    Dim A() As String

    ReDim A(0, 1)
    A(0, 0) = "row 0, col 0"
    A(0, 1) = "row 0, col 1"

    C.Add A(0), "first" ' subscript out of range error

    Debug.Print C.Item("first")(0) & ", " & C.Item("first")(1)
End Sub
```

So, I just want to have an array as a member of a collection.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looking for a collection, but for a dictionary.

1. Add `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your references (Tools/References);
2. Slightly revise your code using a dictionary instead of a collection:

   ```
   Sub test()
      Dim C As New Scripting.Dictionary '<-- not collection
      Dim A() As String

      ReDim A(0, 1)
      A(0, 0) = "row 0, col 0"
      A(0, 1) = "row 0, col 1"

      C.Add "first", A '<-- key first, item then

      Debug.Print C("first")(0, 0) & ", " & C("first")(0,1) <-- you need to access the elements properly (bi-dimensional)

   End Sub
   ```

As for the error ("subscript out of range"), it depends on a bad use of the array. You define it as `A(0 to 0, 0 to 1)` so you cannot use it as if it was uni-dimensional.

Comment: "You are not looking for a collection, but for a dictionary." Why do you say that?  The second part of your answer is the solution but I'm curious about the first part. Why not use a Collection.